# Dry herb identification

Tags: identification, herbs

[image]

Hi all! I bought this at the local farmers market from a little old lady in the sub-tropical part of Turkey, I think the lady said it was St. John's Wort but it doesn't looks like the photos online. Can anybody help me identify it? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a greek mountain tea. Not a St. John's wort but an ironwort.
Makes a great Mediterranean tea.

[Here's More: Wikipedia/ Sideritis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideritis)

Comment: Thank you so much Jayparth! I really appreciate it, have a wonderful day and happy new year!

Comment: Thanks for your kind words! Have a cheerful and prosperous new year!

Comment: @Burcu in my experience this delicious tea needs a lot more steaming to extract the flavor compared to paper bag types of ground herbs. Random online articles even recommend boiling instead of steaming. Also do use the whole thing, no part is discarded.